# Angular 4 Routing Issues

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular does not seem to be loading the components that I configure to the empty `''` path.

Here is my project set up:

```
project/
|- app/
|   |- landing-page/
|   |- second-page/
|   |- third-page/
|   |- app-routing.module.ts
|   |- app.component.html
|   |- app.component.ts
|   `- app.module.ts
|- index.html
`- main.ts
```

app-routing.component.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
        path: '',
        loadChildren: 'app/landing-page/landing-page.module#LandingPageModule'
    },{
        path: 'second',
        loadChildren: 'app/second-page/second-page.module#SecondPageModule'
    },{
        path: 'third',
        loadChildren: 'app/third-page/third-page.module#ThirdPageModule'
    },{
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/'
}]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes,
           { enableTracing: true }
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AnguTest</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

landing-page.component.ts (all 3 components are declared just like this):

```
const landingRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: LandingPageComponent }
]
export const landingRouting = RouterModule.forChild(landingRoutes)

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    landingRouting
  ],
  declarations: [LandingPageComponent]
})
export class LandingPageModule { }
```

The problem is whenever I navigate to the app in my browser, the output is always:

```
second-page works!
```

Even when I change the url to `http://localhost:4200/` or `http://localhost:4200/third`, I only ever see the out put of the 2nd page.

I have tried to rearrange the route declaration order but it is still always the second-page.

If its helpful, I have included the output from the Chrome console. It looks like the app is identifying the route correctly.

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')
NavigationStart
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Router Event: RoutesRecognized
RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
RoutesRecognized
Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
GuardsCheckStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
GuardsCheckStart
Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
GuardsCheckEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } , shouldActivate: true)
GuardsCheckEnd
Router Event: ResolveStart
ResolveStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
ResolveStart
Router Event: ResolveEnd
ResolveEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
ResolveEnd
Router Event: NavigationEnd
NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/')
NavigationEnd
```

**========== RESOLVED ==========**

The problem was that I did not actually declare the route config in all of my modules:

```
// this bit....
const landingRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: LandingPageComponent }
]
export const landingRouting = RouterModule.forChild(landingRoutes)
```

The empty path `''` was not working because I was importing the Modules which I was routing to in `app.module.ts`, effectively doing a double import and causing weird behavior.

After removing the `FirstPageModule` and `SecondPageModule` from the imports list, the issue was resolved.

See this answer for more details:
[Default route redirect not working for lazy loaded routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874687/default-route-redirect-not-working-for-lazy-loaded-routes-in-angular-2/41885916#41885916)

Comment: not sure if you can lazy load the bootstraping first module

Comment: I am actually not too sure what about this config makes it lazy load.. should I try changing `loadChildren` -> `component` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Changing the route to some thing like this

```
  const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path:'',
      redirectTo: 'first',
      pathMatch: 'full' 
    },
    {
      path: 'first',
      loadChildren: 'app/landing-page/landing-page.module#LandingPageModule'
    }, 
    {
     path: 'second',
     loadChildren: 'app/second-page/second-page.module#SecondPageModule'
    }, 
    {
     path: 'third',
     loadChildren: 'app/third-page/third-page.module#ThirdPageModule'
   }, 
   {
     path: '**',
     redirectTo: '/'
  }];
```

Comment: Wow, this is weird.. I updated to match your suggestion. Same thing - all routes only output `second-page works!` EXCEPT for `http://localhost:4200/first` which actually shows the first-page.component.html

Comment: @Mac i didint get the error can you tell the error a bit clearly

Comment: `http://localhost:4200/` routes to `second.component.html`...
 
`http://localhost:4200/second` routes to `second.component.html`...

`http://localhost:4200/third` routes to `second.component.html`...

`http://localhost:4200/first` routes to `landing.component.html`...

Comment: why do you route wild card routes to '`/'` better use a 404 tyoe component or wild card component can you try that ?

Comment: I was routing to '/' just as a test to try to get the landing page to load. I removed the wild card route and it did not affect the problem.

Comment: if possible can you check the third page module ? once by chance you might have done some typo or copying erro can you re verfiy as this should and works for me too

Comment: I forgot to include the routing configuration in the third component! I am able to access all of the routes now when I use the corresponding URL. The only problem is it seems to always default to `second-page`, even with the redirect to `first`. Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: it should redirect to first , please reverify the modules once more . this should work

Comment: I double checked.. I don't think the redirect is being triggered. This is a snippet from my Chrome console: `NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/')`... here is the route defenition copy/pasted withouth any edits: `{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }` (i am using home instead of first )

Comment: @Mac try adding this `redirectTo: '/first'` . the above should work but just as a trail, also the path match must be there

Comment: Added the slash, but it is still the same result. Chrome console gives the same output as above. I'm not sure if there is a way to debug the redirect logic or not..

Comment: @Mac remove slash then, hope you didn't forget the Pathmatch full?

Comment: pathmatch is still here. After removing the slash, here is the route object again (without edits): `{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }`

Comment: Why redirect to home it should be first ?

Comment: I used 'first'/'second'/'third' to make the example simple and clear. My project uses other names for routes, but that is the only difference

Comment: @Mac now you habe confused me too.  The actuall should be the name of your first route thats it it should redirect or if it is home change path first to home

Comment: Ok, I have changed the names to `first`, `second`, and `third` as described above. Still experiencing the issue

Comment: Thanks for the link @Rahul. I'll do a bit more digging, but I think this issue requires another question. Ill accept your post as the answer since it lead me to resolve a few of my problems. Thanks for all your help on this!